# JavaScript if Statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What error in the following code would result in if(is1Pressed = true) console logging "1" repeatedly in console

```
 if(is1Pressed = true){
    console.log("1");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is2Pressed = true) {
        console.log=("2");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
else if(is3Pressed = true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if(is4Pressed = true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if(is5Pressed = true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else 
{
  p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
```

Comment: For the same reason it would happen in *any other language*? `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Next time, try running your code through [JSLint](http://jslint.com). It will catch simple errors like these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `=`, the assignment operator, instead of `==` or `===`. That said, you can stop checking explicitly against `true` and just check the variable's truthiness for more concise code:

```
if (is1Pressed) {
    console.log("1");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if (is2Pressed) {
    console.log = ("2");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if (is3Pressed) {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if (is4Pressed) {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if (is5Pressed) {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
```

Comment: Givin I am new to JavaScript, what's the difference.

Comment: `=` assigns. See how you use it to assign a string to `p.innerHTML`? On the other hand, `==` and `===` are comparison operators. They evaluate to boolean values depending on whether or not their operands are equal.

Comment: "=" is assignment and "==" is condition. so if you do is1Pressed = true, you are assigning the value true to is1Pressed. and if you use is1Pressed == true, then you are check if the value of is1Pressed is true

Comment: Ok it works now but the insertion of the code now runs on instead of letting the audio play, any ideas?

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure what you're asking, but perhaps you should lay this question to rest, and ask a follow-up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `is1Pressed == true`. Otherwise you're saying that is1Pressed is equal to true instead of checking if it's equal to it.

Comment: @paulpro - I'm aware that `1 !== true`. But `1 == true`. Now that we have the useless info out of the way; there is nothing wrong with checking if a variable is `==` to true. He's not checking if 1 is equal to true, he's checking if a variable is equal to true.

Comment: You said that he is saying is1Presssed is equal to 1. He's not saying that when he writes `is1Pressed = true`. He is saying is1Pressed is equal to true, ***not*** 1.

Comment: There also is something wrong with `if(x == true) is general`. It should just be `if(x)` unless he meant `===`.

Comment: @paulpro - Oh, I see where the confusion is, I accidentally put `1` instead of `true`. It's updated now.

Comment: @paulpro - Can you explain what's wrong with using `if(x == true)`? Why does it have to be `if(x)`? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, they mean the same thing. `if(x)` is just more concise, and 8 bytes smaller when it comes to users downloading the js file. :P

Comment: @paulpro - OK, I thought they meant the same thing. I do get the smaller size and it's easier to type and read even, but I just wanted to make sure that I understood correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is the assignment operator, not comparison. Normally for comparisons you should use `===` but since you are trying comparing to `true` you do not need any comparison at all (I'm assuming is1Pressed is a boolean):

```
if(is1Pressed = true){
```

Should be:

```
if(is1Pressed){
```

Same goes for all your other if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "==" and not "=" to check the condition

```
if(is1Pressed == true){
    console.log("1");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is2Pressed == true) {
        console.log=("2");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
else if(is3Pressed == true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if(is4Pressed == true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else if(is5Pressed == true) {
 p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
else 
{
  p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
}
```