# Using Keys to play sound Js

Tags: javascript, audio, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently I have:

```
is1Pressed = false,
is2Pressed = false,
is3Pressed = false,
is4Pressed = false,
is5Pressed = false,
is6Pressed = false,
p = document.getElementById('p');

function loop() {
  if(is1Pressed == true){
    console.log("1");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is2Pressed == true) {
    console.log=("2");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is3Pressed == true) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is4Pressed == true) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(is5Pressed == true) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else 
  {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }

}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    // 1
  case 49:
    is1Pressed = true;
    break;
    // 2
  case 50:
    is2Pressed = true;
    break;
    // 3 
  case 51:
    is3Pressed = true;
    break;
    // 4
  case 52:
    is4Pressed = true;
    break;
    // 5
  case 53:
    is5Pressed = true;
    break;
    //6      
  case 54:
    is6Pressed = true;
    break;
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    // 1
  case 49:
    is1Pressed = false;
    break;
    // 2
  case 50:
    is2Pressed = false;
    break;
    // 3 
  case 51:
    is3Pressed = false;
    break;
    // 4
  case 52:
    is4Pressed = false;
    break;
    // 5
  case 53:
    is5Pressed = false;
    break;
    //6      
  case 54:
    is6Pressed = false;
    break;

  }
}, false);

var framesPerSecond = 60,
  intervalId = setInterval(loop, framesPerSecond / 1000);
```

But when I press the 1 key to play the sample sound the console.log of "1" runs on and the sound never initializes.  What am I doing wrong? Also when the page is inactive the sound loops.

Comment: Do any errors show up in the browser console? Is there actually an element with ID `"p"`? Also - remember [what I said about explicitly checking against `true` in an `if` statement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8622826/139010)...

Comment: No errors display,  yes there is a paragraph with the id of "p"

Comment: Are you using the HTML5 doctype? A browser that supports the `<audio>` element? Which browser?

Comment: When i press and hold the audio tag flashes up...i think what's happening is its checking if(is1Pressed == true){
 if(p.innerHTML != one){
       p.innerHTML = one;
    }
  }
and constantly generating and removing the element

Comment: That sounds reasonable. In that case you should only set the `innerHTML` when the button state _changes_.

Comment: Just to let you know, your frames per second logic is incorrect. Say I wanted to do something at 2fps. I do it every 500ms. That's 1000ms / 2. So 60fps is 1000ms/60, not 60/1000ms.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know what's wrong, though I did notice all of the different if/else cases try to play the same sound, and the final else case will leave a sound playing even when no keys are pressed (or it would if the sounds worked for you at all).

The current structure of your `loop()` function means that (if it worked) only one sound would be played at a time, so why are you keeping track of which keys are pressed simultaneously with the keyup and keydown handlers? You could probably just use keyup to stop all sounds, and then in keydown start the sound that goes with whatever key was just pressed - I'm assuming your intention is for the sound to keep going only as long as the key is held down.

So:

```
var currentKey = 0,
    p = document.getElementById('p');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  var key = e.keyCode-48;

  if (currentKey != key)
     p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button" + key + ".wav'/>";

  currentKey = key;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  p.innerHTML = "";
  currentKey = 0;
}, false);
```

Anyway, if you wanted to try to stick more or less with your current mechanism you can tidy up your code somewhat by getting rid of all the separate key flags and the switch statements in the keyup/down handlers and using a single object to maintain the state of all keys:

```
var keyState = {},
    p = document.getElementById('p');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  keyState[e.keyCode-48] = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  keyState[e.keyCode-48] = false;
}, false);

function loop() {
  if(keyState["1"]){
    console.log("1");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button1.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(keyState["2"]) {
    console.log=("2");
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button2.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(keyState["3"]) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button3.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(keyState["4"]) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button4.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(keyState["5"]) {
   p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button5.wav'/>";
  }
  else if(keyState["6"]) {
  {
    p.innerHTML = "<audio autoplay='autoplay' src='button6.wav'/>";
  }
  else {
    p.innerHTML = "";
  }    
}

var framesPerSecond = 60,
  intervalId = setInterval(loop, framesPerSecond / 1000);
```